# How can I share inbuilt wifi adapter in guest linux os using virtualbox (Here No USB adapter used)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, ethernet

Installed Linux OS in virtualBox over windows 10 where I want to mount existing/internal laptop wifi adapter in guest os (in linux) as a bridge.

Problem : If I mapping laptop wifi to guest os then I will see `Network adapter` but Its should be view wifi(`wlan0`) inside the linux.

Current issue :

```
Laptop wifi --> virtualBox mapping option (Wifi to Network adapter(eth0))-->eth0 (It would be wlan0)
```

[image: config]

Requirement is as below :

```
Laptop wifi --> Virtualbox --> wlan0 (Linux)

=> Unable to bridge the on-board wireless adapter
```

Able to see USB wifi adapter but I want to used inbuild laptop wifi adapter using virtualbox

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking about this in terms of Hardware Devices, instead of Virtual devices.

Virtualbox is a form of virtualisation hypervisor. This means that it is *emulating* all hardware in order that virtual machines may run independently of the host. It virtualises your processor, memory, disk space/partitions, as well as network interfaces. Virtualbox always visualises at least one of each by default.

Now that we have this cleared up, and we are clear that you do currently have a virtual network interface for your machine, I will make the assumption that you are trying to establish network communication between your host network, and the virtualbox guest network.

Your Machine -> Settings -> Network ->

- Ensure the virtual network adapter is enabled
- Ensure the virtual network adapter attached via the `bridged adapter` setting.
- Ensure the virtual network adapter is set to use your hardware wireless adapter to tunnel traffic through.
  [image: Like so]

Comment: I'm not convinced that your assumption about OP being confused is correct. They could actually want to passthrough a PCI-e device from host.

Comment: Perhaps, however attempting to directly mount hardware to a guest like this is likely not the end goal they are trying to achieve. They likely only want to access network connectivity; which would be via virtualisation the device rather than directly interfacing with the hardware (which should not be possible). Also OP said this is a laptop, therefore no PCI-e passthrough.

Comment: @paddywan If I selected `bridged adapter` then its mapping with cable ethernet adapter like eth0 in linux. but goal is to see wifi adapter(wlan0) in linux where i can see `SSID` and used it.

Comment: Is your wireless adapter not available via the second drop-down list?

Comment: Yes, no wireless options on second drop down....that's a problem.

Comment: Are you sure your wireless device is actually working and correctly attached to your host OS? This does not seem like a virtualbox issue. Virtualbox will show a list of all available hardware adapters. what is the primary connection method for your host OS? Through this wireless adapter or via an Ethernet connection? If you are using multiple adapters it could be the case that your wireless has not been correctly installed, or is not detected by the host OS. Please can you confirm that the host recognises the wireless adapter in Device Manager, and run `'ipconfig /all` confirming its connected

Comment: That's irrelevant. Connections bridged to a wireless adapter will still show up as wired Ethernet on guest.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding something here @gronostaj, OP has said he is unable to bridge the wireless adapter.

Comment: @paddywan That's irrelevant, because as I said connections bridged to a wireless adapter will show up as a wired Ethernet adapter in guest. That's literally what I said in my comment. Bridging is not the solution because OP wants the adapter to appear as a wireless adapter, and all networking options in Virtualbox create a virtual wired adapter. So virtual adapters are out. Passthrough of the physical adapter is necessary.

Comment: Please quote me the part where OP "wants the adapter to appear as a wireless adapter"

Comment: @paddywan _"but goal is to see wifi adapter(wlan0) in linux where i can see `SSID` and used it"_, from OP's first comment on this answer.

Comment: @paddywan Also from the question: _"I want to mount existing/internal laptop wifi adapter in guest os"_ and _"If I mapping (sic) laptop wifi to guest os then I will see Network adapter but Its should be view wifi(wlan0) inside the linux"_

Comment: Well, its a little difficult to accurately translate this broken english alongside a confused concept of what the desired goal is, would you not concurr? Regardless, both his question title, and his footnote specifically ask the question that I answered with no confusion.

Comment: @gronostaj  I simplify in question. As i see, you understand the problem well. Hope you something find out for same.